# Can I access tables on SQL Server and DB2 from Mainframe Cobol Programs via BizTalk DRDA Services?

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, cobol, mainframe, db2-zos

We have Mainframe z/OS COBOL applications accessing set of DB2 tables (T1, T2) from few applications (App1, App2) in a SELECT query. Now, we are moving one of the application (App1) and its tables (T1) to SQL Server (Azure SQL in the future). How do we move this application without impacting the Mainframe COBOL applications?

Can we use BizTalk Host Integration Server DRDA services to expose the table T1 from SQL Server and Table T2 from DB2 and allow the Mainframe COBOL applications to continue to join the tables and run SELECT queries? In otherwords, Mainframe COBOL wouldn't even know the table T1 is not in DB2 but in SQL Server?
The following link from Microsoft says doable, but would like to understand the feasibility and Pros/Cons.

- IBM DRDA - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRDA, https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0206.htm
- Configuring DB2 for z-OS - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/core/configuring-db2-for-z-os
- DRDA services available in BizTalk - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/core/service-for-drda

Comment: Even if do-able, it might not be a good idea. You need to find out *how* and *how often* the table is used on the mainframe. Then talk to the DBA's. If the table is used 10000 times a day in a Cics transaction, it would be a very bad idea.

Comment: The Table will be used few hundred thousand times per hour, mIllions per day. But it is not accessed through CICS. Mainframe COBOL programs access the table directly.

Comment: I would be talking to the DBA's; I would guess you need to replicate the Table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going out on a limb here but I think the answer is NO. z/OS COBOL programs access DB2 using threads to a local DB2 subsystem via cross-memory services. Think of it like a socket but done using low-level zero copy inter-process-communication. To do what you require would need application changes and Java in the mix to integrate to BizTalk.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a DRDA link to an OCDB database link which should allow you to connect to almost any standard SQL database on another server. But you would probably not get it past your mainframe sysadmins's as it is non standard 
and difficult to manage.

Replication would probably be your best bet -- there are several tools from both vendors:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/ibm-db2-subscribers?view=sql-server-2017 describes the Microsoft offering.